# How to resolve polynomials with just two terms where one of them is a constant

Tags: polynomials

1) I have the information that to resolve:
$$
x^n = 3*x^{n-4}
$$

2) I would need to solve
$$
x^4 = 3
$$

3) Whose positive value would be:
$$
x = 3^{1/4}.
$$

4) Which is then:
$$
x = \sqrt[3]{4}.
$$

The question is then: how to get form point 1 to point 2? More precisely: How the first equation got simplified; and how the -4 exponent got positive and the 3 ended up on the other side.

Thanks.

Comment: As currently written, the connection between (1) and (2) is not correct: Multiplying both sides of (1) by $x^4$ yields $x^{n+4} = 3$, not $x^4 = 3$.  Or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: You are right, apologies. I think I fixed it now. It is on the context of branching algorithms, and the original step before step 1 was: T(n) = 3*T(n-4). So, it's an algorithm that does 3 branches, each branch reducing the instance size by 4. From T(n) = 3*T(n-4) then one would get to the formula in 1.

Comment: I think the simplification is somehow dividing 1 by $x^n$, but not sure how the exponent gets positive.

Comment: If you're doing complexity recurrences, by the way, you should ensure that it's reasonable to ignore any fixed-time component: that is, that the recurrence isn't better written as $T(n) = 3T(n-4)+O(1)$.

Comment: You can think of the simplification as first dividing by $x^n$, and then multiplying by $x^4$.  Or, you can do them both in one step by multiplying by $x^{4-n}$.

Comment: I think it is reasonable for me as the final notation is the O* notation, thus we are just interested in the exponential factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You multiply both sides by $x^{4-n}$ to get

$$
x^{n+4-n} = 3 \cdot x^{n-4+4-n}
$$

which we can simplify to obtain

$$
x^4 = 3 \cdot x^0 = 3
$$

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand it.